# "in the morning" vs "on cold mornings"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, time

I always know is "in the morning" until I read this article ["should I let my vehicle warm up **on cold mornings**?"](https://www.autocampusa.com/should-i-let-my-vehicle-warm-up-on-cold-mornings/)

Why did it use "on cold mornings" instead of "in cold mornings" ? Is it because there is an adjective "old" before mornings then we use **on** instead of **in**? Does this rule apply to **in the afternoon** and **in the evening** too ?

Comment: Yes, the same rule applies, for example, to "***on** hot afternoons*" and "***on** clear evenings*", but I don't have an answer why. For what it's worth, it works the same with singular times: "*on **a** hot afternoon*" and "*on **a** clear evening*".

Comment: There is also the usage _of a morning_ meaning in the mornings which i think is possibly a dialect usage. I have no idea why we say any of these things though.

Answer (score 1):

**On** is often used to reference days, or events that last less than a day, (On every Tuesday, on rare occasions, on a cold winter's night). Mornings, for example, only happen once a day. The sentence concerns the occurrence of specific thing - when it happens. It is not about the car being in the morning (that sounds silly). It is about what to do with your car **when** the cold morning occurs.